# How send 2 variable to JavaScript Function from Onclick event in Same JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I am calling a JavaScript Function inside the same Javascript file on OnClick. right now I am sending 1 variable to that method, I need to send 2 variable. Any Syntax that I am trying is not working.

That is my call:

```
 headerDiv.innerHTML += "<div id='sort' data-sort='false'><a onClick= SortData('" + header  + "')>" + header + '&#8595;' + "</a></div>";
```

I need to send ascSort as well. 
this is my JavaScript function:

```
  function SortData(header, ascSort) {
   ...
   }
```

Comment: what do you mean by " i am trying but not working"... as in you passed in a second param argument but it's not working??? because at the moment you're only passing in 1 argument.

Comment: if ascSort is a string then it should work the same way header is working. Can you put an example of what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda hard to answer without knowing exactly what ascSort represents, but in case it's a string, it should do the work:

```
headerDiv.innerHTML +=
"<div id='sort' data-sort='false'>" +
"<a onClick=\"return SortData('" + header + "',"' + ascSort + '")>"
+ header + '&#8595;' + "</a></div>";
```

And in case it's not, just remove the apostrophe around the ascSort, like this:

```
headerDiv.innerHTML +=
"<div id='sort' data-sort='false'>" +
"<a onClick=\"return SortData('" + header + "'," + ascSort + ")>"
+ header + '&#8595;' + "</a></div>";
```